# Python Mechanize: submit button will not work no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, mechanize

There is a form on this webpage: https://www.avanza.se/mina-sidor/kontooversikt.html

I am trying to fill in and submit it using this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cookielib 
import urllib2 
import mechanize 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html 
import urllib2, base64, lxml
import numpy as np
import unicodedata
import datetime
import re
import time

URL = "https://www.avanza.se/mina-sidor/kontooversikt.html"

br = mechanize.Browser() 

cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar() 
br.set_cookiejar( cookiejar ) 

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615  Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.open(URL)

for f in br.forms():
    if f.attrs['class'] == 'loginForm clearFix':
        br.f = f
    print f
        break

br.f[ "j_username" ] = "user"
br.f[ "j_password" ] = "pass"

res = br.submit() 

time.sleep(5)

br.open('https://www.avanza.se/handla/aktier.html/kop/5447/abb-ltd')

#Getting the response in beautifulsoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read(), 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify().encode("utf-8"))
```

And my print verifies i get correct form:

```
<div class="section accordion-togglebar">
  <a class="toggleBar whiteBG normalBlack noTopBorder ubuntu active" href="#" data-login-method="userCredentials">
    <img src="/jmvc/avanzabank/images/inloggningsuppgifter_ic.svg" class="loginTypeIcon" alt="Inloggningsuppgifter" title="Inloggningsuppgifter">
    Användarnamn &amp; lösenord <span class="arrow fRight"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="toggleBarContent noPaddingTop ">
    <div class="messageWrapper formLogin"></div>
    <form autocomplete="off" class="loginForm clearFix" method="POST" action="/ab/noop">
      <input placeholder="Användarnamn" type="text" name="j_username" autocapitalize="none">
      <input placeholder="Lösenord" type="password" name="j_password">
      <button class="focusBtn loginButton marginTop5px marginBottom15px errorToolTipPlacement fRight" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Logga in</button>

      <a class="marginTop4px defaultSize plcLink" href="/glomt-uppgift.html">Glömt lösenord eller användarnamn?</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

However when i try to submit i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap_mec.py", line 91, in <module>
    res = br.submit() 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
    return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 530, in click
    request = self.form.click(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have to use the `select_form` method so that the browser knows which form you're trying to submit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```py
res = br.submit()
```

You need to do the following:

In the click method you must pass the value of the name attribute from HTML to the button, where type = "submit".

```py
request = form.click(name=<name>)  # or form.click(id=<id>)
br.open(request)
```